# Why there is two output in Titanic case in tflearn quickstart?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tflearn

i'm a beginner on this field, i've tried tflearn for a while and stuck in the quickstart guide in this link.

http://tflearn.org/tutorials/quickstart.html

i've tried that and it works perfectly with accuracy around 78%, but the problem is i don't understand why the "labels" consist of two "survived" columns that opposite each other. i've done train the same data but used only single "survived" column in the labels or the output, but with the same code i just get around 36% with 0 loss or even NaN loss.

so why is there two columns output/labels? and why can't i use only a single column?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

The two different columns represent onehot encoded label. You can check how its done [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html) Which is usually choice of last layer with softmax activation function.

But if you want to replace that with one, you need to also change the activation function to sigmoid. Also don't forget to change load_csv code to `n_classes=1`. and Here is the sample code for building the model:

```
# Build neural network
net = tflearn.input_data(shape=[None, 6])
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 32)
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 32)
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 1, activation='sigmoid')
net = tflearn.regression(net)
```

This will produce probability of being survived.